# Should I be concerned about my Litecoin pool not showing anything but my invalid shares?

Tags: litecoin

I have recently begun mining Litecoin and am still fairly new to the crypto-currency community. My main concern at the moment is that whenever I log into my account on litecoinpool.org (the pool that I have chosen to mine in), and view my worker's stats, the only thing that shows up is the amount of invalid shares I have. All of my worker's other stats are at 0, yet my mining software is telling me that I am mining at 50Mh/s and I have accepted over 230 shares. Does this mean that I should be concerned about not receiving rewards or is it simply a delay in the site reflecting my other stats?

P.S In case it is of any importance, I have been mining for a total amount of about 8 hours.

Comment: What hardware and software are you using to mine? It's possible you're using SHA256d mining gear which will definitely not mine Litecoins.

Comment: I am mining on an NVIDIA GeForce 840m, on guiminer 2012-12-03 my current miner is using OpenCL.

Comment: You're doing something terribly wrong because the 840m can only do about 40Kh/s. My bet is that you're doing the SHA256d algorithm that Bitcoin uses and not the scrypt algorithm that Litecoin uses.